# Is there a way to reuse the Port of a Clientconnection after closing it in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, nullpointerexception, port

I wanted to implement a little restart functionality in my code.
The user should be able to restart the ClientConnection, with the same Port.

My main class openes a new ClientConnection with the Port 4442, i later want to close the connection (I tried to close the Socket and the Serversocket) to then create a new Instance of the Class.

I have two Problems now:
First an port is bound exception is thrown and a Nullpointerexception.

```
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    Socket clientsocket;


    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4442);
            System.out.println("Server is running");

            clientsocket = serverSocket.accept();
            PrintWriter out =
                    new PrintWriter(clientsocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(clientsocket.getInputStream()));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server();
        new Thread(server).start();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    server.clientsocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
        new Thread(new Server()).start();
    }
} 


 Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Server$1.run(Server.java:40)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Server is running
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) 


Am I overseeing something obvious or is it not possible to reuse the same port.
 I've read some posts about the close-Method in another Thread. 

This line:   server.clientsocket.close(); is throwing a nullpointer exception too and i don't know why.
```

Comment: Your first thread launches the server. It waits for a connection, which could come in at ANY time (could take a long time). Second thread tries to close, but doesn't wait on anything; it starts basically right away. It wound up executing before the first thread could assign the `server` variable in a public way, hence the NPE & server not closing. You then try to launch another `Server` instance even though the previous wasn't closed due to the errors mentioned above. Keep in mind, threads do not wait for each other unless you tell them to. Your code lacks thread coordination.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Can this be fixed with synchronising on the server object ? or do i need to work with Locks / Conditions.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do: "i later want to close the connection" -- what does "later" mean? When is"later"? Currently you're trying to close the "client socket" before it even exists

Comment: You would need to have the 2nd thread `wait` for the 1st thread to `notify` it. After the 1st thread notifies the 2nd, the 2nd would notify the 3rd to start a new connection. But do you really need all these threads to do what you want?

Comment: Well, I wanted a restart option, but I start thinking about , that's its not worth the effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A probable cause of "BindException: Address already in use" is that the operating system is keeping the port reserved for a while after the application stops,  in case there are still outstanding connections sending packets to it. You can solve that by enabling "address reuse" on the socket:

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(4442));
```

The NullPointerException is caused by a race condition: the second thread is trying to close the client connection before it has even been accepted. There is no way the code in the question could work, so I'm guessing it's not your real code.

Comment: thanks for the answer. This is a piece of my code, which I exported for easier testing. And yes, it is not working otherwise i wouldn't have asked :)

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. Next time I might show the main code and not my testing examples. Thanks for the help.